# "Boot device not found" when I try to boot after system installation with USB

Tags: boot, system-installation

After installing Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS I pressed **restart now**, then

> remove the installation medium and reboot

appeared (although it should instead say *press enter*).

I pulled the USB out and to restart the laptop I pressed the power button.

Now boot freezes with `boot device not found`. I have changed BIOS boot priority to HDD, but it didn't help.

Comment: suggested edit. hope my answer will solve your problem.

Comment: Boot Device not found is a UEFI/BIOS type error before grub even loads. From USB installer you can choose to install in either UEFI or BIOS boot mode by how you boot install media  UEFI or BIOS. but then system or actual install must be set to boot in that same boot mode. If you install in BIOS mode but have UEFI on it will not find an UEFI boot loader. How did you install and then check settings in UEFI/BIOS to make sure they match. If not: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  Also what brand/model system.

Comment: edited anwer based on comments :) I hope it helps you now

Comment: let us know if you have another PC around, I will update the answer with easier solution...

Answer (score 0):

> **Based on comments above** and the fact that the installation pops out a let me say different kind of button as expected, now it seems to me as install hangs with error forcing it to quit and waiting for restart before grub properly configured itself.

**Long story short** as you can boot to live USB session, you are able to reinstall grub from there and everything should work as expected then.
**[Long story](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)** • How to reinstall grub using live USB

---

> Double check whether you accidentally installed bootloader on that installation USB or on HDD. You can do that simply by booting with that USB inserted.

**Nevertheless, if you can access grub rescue then start from there.** If you see the `grub rescue >` shell (right after the boot error message), continue typing `ls` to list your drives and partitions. You will see something like:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2)
```

Check them one by one if you don't know which has the system installed on it.

```
ls (hd0,msdos1)/
ls (hd0,msdos2)/
```

The right one should have listed `lost+found` dir etc.

Assuming `(hd0,msdos2)` is the right one, we can continue by setting grub root and going out of rescue mode to the normal terminal, where more magic is available.

```
set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,2)
insmod normal
normal
```

> **You will be able to `boot` from here**, but if only some rare errors occurs, you can still set the boot image manually as it follows.

```
insmod linux 
* linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda
ro
```

Optionally, you can select the `initrd` image, too.

```
initrd /initrd.img
```

---

**After `boot`, you have to reinstall grub from terminal and set it to boot from your hard drive.**

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```